# SQL 2008 R2 Recursive Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion

I have the following SQLtable

```
[rel_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[rel_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[left_object_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[left_object_type] [int] NOT NULL,
[right_object_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[right_object_type] [int] NOT NULL,
[template] [char](1) NOT NULL
```

Basically this table controls relationships between different objects.  I’ need to construct some SQL that given left_object_id can work out recursively all the objects that has relationships to it.

I’m only interested in object where both the left & right object types are 5

In simple terms the SQL would need to do the following
1.  Input a left object id 
2.  Search the table and return all right object ids where associated left object matches the input
3.  For each of the right object id found go back repeat from step 1
4.  Repeat until no further values are found

Sounds complex, but I’m sure there is some SQL guru out there who can solve this.

Many Thanks.

Comment: So far what you have tried ? Can you show it so we can carry from there

Comment: My efforts so far have been to use C# methods, but this is not very efficient as it involves too many database calls.

Comment: Read about [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Please post some sample data

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without test data but something like this should do the trick:

I assume a tree, having one parent element left side and a children list right side. This query should come back with entries having their parent of type 5 and at least one child of type 5.

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE (SELECT leftObj.rel_type_id FROM @tbl AS leftObj WHERE leftObj.right_object_id=tbl.rel_id)=5
  AND EXISTS(SELECT rightObjList.rel_type_id 
             FROM @tbl AS rightObjList 
             WHERE rightObjList.left_object_id=tbl.rel_id
               AND rightObjList.rel_type_id=5)
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>rel_id</th><th>rel_type_id</th><th>left_object_id</th><th>left_object_type</th><th>right_object_id</th><th>right_object_type</th></tr><tr><td>52</td><td>44</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>53</td><td>44</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>54</td><td>44</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>55</td><td>44</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: I just re-read your question and got the feeling, that I haven't understood this properly... Please provide test data and expected output example!

Comment: I've read through the CTE stuff, kind of understand it, from it I have produced this, but it stops after one level:  
`WITH relations AS 
( 
SELECT left_object_id, right_object_id  
FROM relationships 
WHERE left_object_id = 5
UNION ALL

SELECT r1.right_object_id, r2.left_object_id
  FROM relations AS r1
    INNER JOIN dbo.relationships AS r2
      ON r1.left_object_id = r2.right_object_id
)
SELECT * FROM relations`

Comment: sorry that formatted badly, I do have it formatted better, but it exceeds the char limit - any ideas?

Comment: yes I think so, in the interim I've stuck the code here:

Comment: Please poste the desired output too

Comment: I think I got this wrong completely... Is the following correct: There is kind of an "object" catalogue (IDs 1,3,4,5,6) and your table is defining a many-to-many relationship? If so: Why don't you use an "object" table and mark the object's type there? And again: please post the desired output for this small set of test data.